# Very small domains in FF1 or similar

Tags: format-preserving

I want a family of efficiently computable random-ish bijections $f_{k,n} : [0..n) \to [0..n)$ for $n \le 2048$.  We cannot make the $f_{k,n}$ be secure for encryption at this domain size of course, but I really only need the set $f_{k,n}\big( [0..n/3) \big)$ to be distributed somewhat randomly.  In particular, those set overlaps should've expected size $n / 3^j$ for $j$ distinct random $k$.

I could simply shuffle $[0..n)$ of course, but format preserving encryption vaguely like FF1 sounds like a better choice for cache locality and convenience.  It appears FF1 itself cannot handle a strings of length one though.

I'll presumably need some other generalized Feistel algorithm adapted to small domains, but which divides the domain algebraically, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a modified affine cipher chain. It's the type of design I developed initially when trying to find a way to scramble database IDs, or name-based / time-based GUIDs without introducing birthday collisions.

Given that you want to express all non-negative integers smaller than $n = 2048$, $n$ is the exclusive maximum, and $m = n-1$ is the inclusive maximum. All those numbers can be expressed in $L = |m|$ number of bits, which in this case $L = 11$ bits. Then, find the first prime number $P_n \ge 2^{L}$, here that would be $P_n = 2053$.

Choose a uniform, random key $k \in \{0, 1\}^{7 \cdot L}$ and slice it into seven equal $L$-size, non-overlapping chunks $k_0$, $k_1$, $k_2$, $k_3$, $k_4$, $k_5$, $k_6$, and convert each of those keys into non-negative integers. Now, $k_3$ and $k_5$ (the multiplication keys) do also need to be non-zero, so you can resample randomly from $\{0, 1\}^L$ until those two don't end up converting into zeros. Then the random-ish, bijective permutation $f_{k,n}(x)$ will be defined like this:

$$\forall k' \space (k' \gt 0)$$
$$g_{k',k''}(x) = y = (k' \cdot x + k'') \mod P_n$$
$$G_{k',k''}(x) = \begin{cases} G_{k',k''}(y) & \text{if } y \ge 2^L \\ y & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
$$f_{k,n}(x) = G_{k_5,k_6}(G_{k_3,k_4}(x \oplus k_0) \oplus k_1) \oplus k_2$$

Because the prime number $P_n$ is larger than the desired range, we have to shrink the range using a recursive definition for $G_{k',k''}(x)$. It uniquely swaps an element $x$ such that $g_{k',k''}(x) \leftrightarrow y$ where $x \lt 2^L$ and $P_n \gt y \ge 2^L$, with another element $x' = y$ such that $g_{k',k''}(x') \leftrightarrow y'$ where $P_n \gt x' \ge 2^L$ and  $y' \lt 2^L$.

For small domains, it's probably worthwhile to increase $C$, the chain of calls to $G_{k',k''}(x)$ within $f_{k,n}(x)$. That's if a keyspace larger than $77$ bits is desired, or a better chance at good random-ish scrambling. The formula $\space |k| = (3 \cdot C + 1) \cdot L \space$ can determine how long a string of bits $k$ will need to be for a chain of calls of length $C$. In my testing on larger domains (where $n \ge 2^{128}$), a chain of length $C \ge 2$ was enough to produce random looking outputs, and break up the obvious bit patterns that are present from only a single call to $G$.

**This solution is:**

- Efficiently computable: Processing each input $x$ would cost about three xors, and an average of two multiplications, two additions and two modulo reductions.
- Bijective: It might not be obvious, but each input $x$ will map to a unique output $y$. It's easier to see by considering if each operation is bijective. If each operation is bijective, then the chain of operations is bijective.
- Small in area: It would take about 77 bits to store the key $k$, and 12 bits to store the prime $P_n$. In total that would be 89 bits.
- Simple to implement: The capacity to perform xor, multiplication and addition modulo a number is ubiquitous. The most challenging operation would be changing the domain of your problem and then determining the next prime number $P_n \ge 2^L$.
- Length preserving: Each permutation result $f_{k,n}(x)$ will fit in the same amount of bits defined by the inclusive maximum number $m$ in your problem domain.

As long as you don't need actual encryption, this could help.

Comment: You defined G as either G... or y. I think you meant it should be either g... or y?

Comment: @J_H $g_{k',k''}(x) = y$; whereas, $G_{k',k''}(x)$ is shorthand for the conditional function that outputs $y$ if $y \lt 2^L$ (is inside of the domain) or calls itself recursively (cycle walks) on its outputs until $y \not \ge 2^L$ (doesn't fall outside of the domain).

Comment: @aiootp can you confirm that the circled + operator is the bitwise XOR?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I'd advise you to reconsider the "shuffle $[0,n)$ solution; such a permutation table (packed) would fit in 2816 bytes (for $n \le 2048$); that's well within the L1 dcache on most non-lowend CPUs (and well within the L2 cache).  And, I would personally suspect that a full cache miss (of both the L1 and the L2 cache) would actually be cheaper than performing an FF1 encryption (which invokes AES 10 times) even with AES-NI would end up taking more cycles.

Or, is the times taken to set up the permutation a concern?  Obviously, generating a 2048 element random shuffle is rather more expensive than, say, selecting a random AES key.

In addition, the current NIST guidance is to not use FF1 for domains $< 1000000$; I don't know if they have any specific weakness in mind, or whether it would impact your relatively modest goals, however that is something to keep in mind.

On the other hand:

> It appears FF1 itself cannot handle a strings of length one though.

That is true; however those are strings of digits; if you select a base of 2 (and so a digit consists of a single bit), FF1 can function perfectly well (with a string of 11 digits), albeit not following the NIST guidance mentioned above.

Comment: AES 10 times per letter?  I guess per chunk of letters, but still that's lots.  AES merely doing key sequence set up could be cached of course, assuming the devs use that option.  We'd only need a full AES or ChaChas for every 16 shuffles, if optimized better than rand::shuffle right now.  I'd need to make our devs cache the table though.  lol

Comment: @JeffBurdges: 10 times per FF1 evaluation (for permutations smaller than 256 bits, which you obviously are).  I have no idea what you're referring to with "a full AES/ChaCha [once] every 16 shuffles"